# IMAP fetch body too slow

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

Trying to get emails from IMAP(gmail) and struggling with the last part.

If I fetch just message headers, for a 85 messages in my inbox, it took 3 seconds:

```
imap.fetch(message_ids, '(BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO CC SUBJECT DATE)])')
```

But if i try to fetch the email body, it takes ~3 minutes:

```
imap.fetch(message_ids, '(RFC822)')
```

or

```
imap.fetch(message_ids, '(BODY.PEEK[TEXT])')
```

or

```
imap.fetch(message_ids, 'RFC822.TEXT')
```

Already tried to set TCP_NODELAY as some thread suggested here.
Same problem with imapClient lib and Twisted imap4 module

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do your bodies include large attachments? Downloading headers is quick because there's not much data, but if you've got lots of 20 mb messages it might take a while... maybe you should fetch bodystructure so you can figure out the main part, and how big it is.

Comment: Thank you! Had to see bodystructure and fetch headers and body in separate. I thought BODY[TEXT] would bring just text content of the body, had to fetch BODY[1]

Comment: Glad to have helped. I'll rearrange my comment into an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those will retrieve the full MIME content of the message, which can be quite large if they include attachments, and will take quite a while.

If you fetch `BODYSTRUCTURE`, you can parse the format/structure of the message, and get an idea of the size before you download it, and where exactly the main "body" part is.